# wix set install location variable from radio button

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.8

I'm trying to set two different install locations using radio buttons (single user installs to AppData and allusers installs to ProgramFiles)

My property is defined as follows:

```
    <Property Id="INSTALLSCOPE" Secure="yes" />
```

My install directory definitions are as follows:

```
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
        <Directory Id= 'INSTALLSCOPE'  Name='AppData'>
            <Directory Id='MYAPP' Name='COMPANY'>
                <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='MyApp'>
```

My radio buttons are as follows:

```
    <Dialog Id="CustomInstallScopeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Install Scope"
                NoMinimize="yes">

        <Control Id="RadioButtonGroupID" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="30" Y="94" Width="305" Height="100" Property="INSTALLSCOPE">

            <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLSCOPE">
                <RadioButton Value="LocalAppDataFolder" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" Height="10" Text="SingleUser"/>
                <RadioButton Value="ProgramFilesFolder" X="0" Y="20" Width="300" Height="10" Text="AllUser"/>
            </RadioButtonGroup>

        </Control>
            ...
```

After the radio buttons are changed and NEXT button is clicked, the following happens:

```
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"
    Text="[ButtonText_Next]">
            <Publish Property="INSTALLSCOPE" Value="LocalAppDataFolder">INSTALLSCOPE = "LocalAppDataFolder"</Publish>
            <Publish Property="INSTALLSCOPE" Value="ProgramFilesFolder">INSTALLSCOPE = "ProgramFilesFolder"</Publish>
    </Control>
```

Currently whats happening when I run it is it tries to install in E:AppData, instead of the correct AppData folder. Also the installer bugs out and the UI doesnt show. This doesnt happen if I hardcode the value `LocalAppDataFolder` instead of passing it through a variable. I ran a log on the install process and I can see the value of INSTALLSCOPE being changed as I go through the installer but the UI never updates to reflect this change and neither does the actual installation path ever change. Any help would be great.

Comment: Try to look into file WixUI_Advanced.wxs (if you did not yet), where is implemented UI template with function, that you are trying to implement. It may help you. I think that the easiest way is just copy InstallScopeDlg things from UI template and create own clone of InstallScopeDlg.wxs and edit it to your needs, or copy functionality from there.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. These templates are found [here](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset) and don't seem to be compatible with newer versions of Wix.

Comment: It is not official WiX repository, it is located here [link](https://github.com/wixtoolset/) . Last week I have used templates from WiX4 branch to WiX3.10 toolset and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a SetTargetPath event:

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"
    Text="[ButtonText_Next]">
    <Publish Property="INSTALLSCOPE" Value="LocalAppDataFolder">INSTALLSCOPE = "LocalAppDataFolder"</Publish>
    <Publish Property="INSTALLSCOPE" Value="ProgramFilesFolder">INSTALLSCOPE = "ProgramFilesFolder"</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="INSTALLSCOPE">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Comment: This gives an error: `The RadioButtonGroup element contains an unexpected child element 'Publish'.`

Comment: Sorry, I have copied the wrong code from the question body. The Publish Event part should be added to Control element. I have edited my answer.